# How to split single column to mutiple column in file

Tags: linux

I have file

```
cat demo.txt

servername
a
b
c
servername
d
f
c
servername
k
f
g
```

i want convert as below

```
servername servername servername
a            d         k
b            f         f
c            c         g
```

using shell.  here `servername` are dynamic

Answer (score 4):

`pr -3T`

```
pr -3T
servername              servername              servername
a                       d                       k
b                       f                       f
c                       c                       g
```

`pr` paginates or columnates data.

`pr -3` will split and print three vertical columns. If more columns were needed, you can increase (or decrease) the count accordingly.

`-T-` 
-T, --omit-pagination
omit page headers and trailers, eliminate any pagination by form feeds set in input files (Taken from man page)